# Measure theory exercise where $\mu(E)=+\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X= \Bbb N$ and $F$ a family of $\Bbb N$. (I guess $F$ is a $\sigma-$algebra).
Also let $\mu: F \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a set function such that 
if $E$ is finite then $\mu(E)=0$, but if $E$ is infinite then $\mu(E)=\infty$.

Is $\mu$ a measure?
Please help, according to the teacher $\mu$ is not a measure I just need to prove it

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). To speed the process, this post has been converted.

Comment: What property must a measure satisfy? Have you tried to check them for $\mu$?

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n \in {\mathbb N}} 0 = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three axioms for a measure are non-negativity, zero measure null set, and countable additivity. If a set function $\mu : 2^X \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}$ satisfies these three axioms then it is awarded the title of measure. It is obvious that non-negativity is true and the null set has zero measure. So the tricky axiom is countable additivity.

Let $\{E_k\}$ be a collection of sets. Let $\{E_k\}$ be the countable infinite collection of finite sets such that $E_k = \{x_k\}$. Then

$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=0} E_i\right) = +\infty \neq \sum_{i=0} 0 = \sum_{i=0} \mu(E_i)$$.

So countable additivity fails for some sets.